# AutoHotKey, Menu, Call AHK script from menu with parameter

Tags: parameters, menu, autohotkey

### It show error target label does not exist

```
Mitems = cmdl,ahk
StringSplit, MitemArray, Mitems, `,
Loop, %MitemArray0%
{
    this_Mitem := MitemArray%a_index% 
    Menu,Menu,Add,%a_index% - %this_Mitem%, %A_ScriptDir%\ksson.ahk %this_Mitem%
}
Menu, Menu, Show
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with this piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Help and what the [Menu add command](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Menu.htm#Add) accepts as LabelOrSubMenu input.

Passing a path to another script is not supported.
You could pass a function define in another file in the same directory.

Something Like:

```
Menu,Menu,Add,%a_index% - %this_Mitem%, ksson
```

And the ksson function either in the same script or in a file in same working dir:

```
ksson(ItemName, ItemPos, MenuName){
; your function
} ; eofun
```